# how to exclude meta data from elasticsearch results?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to exclude this meta data information from the API call? 
I agree this is useful, however, I'm not using that information in anyway for regular transactions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering) for that.